# How to write a function that iterates over anything that provides an iterator

Tags: c++11

In Python it's very easy to iterate over anything that provides an iterator:

```
def iterate(iterable):
    for i in iterable:
        do_something(i)
```

**Is it possible to write a similiar function in C++?**

Other answers suggest something like:

```
template<class iterator_type>
void iterate(iterator_type it, iterator_type end)
{
    while (it != end) {
        do_something(*(it++));
    }
}
```

But is there a way that can directly take something with an iterator and fetches the iterator begin and end by itself?

So after all, the question reduces to: **Is there a standardized way to get an iterator from any object that provides an iterator?** (Like `iter(...)` in Python.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [range for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to iterate over a collection having iterators.

> Is there a standardized way to get an iterator from any object that provides an iterator?

Yes, its `std::begin(...)` and `std::end(...)` functions.